# How to load components in react router only when required?

Tags: reactjs, requirejs, react-router

Consider this example code:

```
require(["js/components/feed-component", "js/components/single-post-component"], function (x, y) {
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
        Router,
        { history: BrowserHistory },
        React.createElement(Route, { path: "/", component: x }),
        React.createElement(Route, { path: "post", component: y})
    ), document.getElementById("appContainer"));
});
```

here `js/components/single-post-component` component is loaded from server even if user never visits the `/post` page.

How can I avoid this? How can I make a component to be loaded only if user visits the URL.

In Angular, `ng-view` a view is loaded when user visits the URL. I want something similar to happen in React also.

Comment: How do you mean "loaded from server?" does that component perform a fetch? W/ React Router, components aren't rendered unless a route is matched

Comment: not really possible, because requiring modules is actually bundling them into a single javascript file and you load it all at once.

Answer (score 4):

I've successfully done but you need to use a bundler like Webpack to achieve it. First you need to split your routes up so that they load dynamically. You can look at the [example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md) on react router for how to dynamically set up your routes. Basically you can defer loading on the components since each route has a `getComponent` method.

```
  ...imports

  let rootRoute = {
    path: '/',
    name: 'root',
    component: require('./containers/App2'),
    indexRoute: {
      getComponent: (location, cb) => {
       return require.ensure([], (require) => {
        cb(null, require('./containers/App'))
       })
     }
  }

  //routes is now an object
  <Router history={appHistory} routes={rootRoute} />
```

So you've deferred the loading of the component that you need until your route is called. This is also a great way to break up modules in your app.

Now in Webpack (sorry the only one I have experience with) it can return only the parts of your application that you visit.

heres the top of my webpack.config file.

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: ['./htdocs/js/index'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'https://localhost:3000/dist/'
  },
  //other settings down here
}
```

The Huge Apps example on react router also shows how this works and I used it as the base of my projects to split up my very large bundle file.

Comment: Thanks, it loads component including css file (which is imported in the component) when needed. If I leave this page (or component), how could I remove the css file?